# Longer labels within li element keep wrapping to the next line

Tags: label, html-lists, display, sidebar, text-align

So I'm struggling to keep items within an LI element inline.
each

is made up of a svg symbol a checkbox and a text label.

when the label is too long, the text wraps to the next line.
I've tried different display display properties with no luck.

[Heres an e.g. of what i'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5RBb.png)

[here's a pen of my attempts so far.](https://codepen.io/10ldavis/pen/MWPbMwp)

Thanks so much for the help it's really appreciated

and yes I'm struggling to get this snippet working... please excuse this

Here the follwing code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gateshead Maps</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <style>
      input[type=checkbox],
      input[type=radio] {
        /* keeping layer checkboxes and patches inline  */
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: relative;
        bottom: .08em;
        /* this is a better value for different fonts! */
        left: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
      }

      svg {
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: relative;
        bottom: .08em;
        margin-left: 20px;
      }

      label {
        padding-left: 12px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #383636;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        display: inline;
        position: center;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left:
      }

      .overflow {
        padding-right: 10px;
      }

      .btn-toggle {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: .25rem .5rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
        background-color: transparent;
      }

      .btn-toggle:hover,
      .btn-toggle:focus {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
        background-color: #e3e4e4;
      }

      .btn-toggle::before {
        width: 1.25em;
        line-height: 0;
        content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'width='16'height='16'viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none'stroke='rgba%280,0,0,.5%29'stroke-linecap='round'stroke-linejoin='round'stroke-width='2'd='M5 14l6-6-6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
transition: transform .35s ease;
            transform-origin: .5em 50%;
        }

        .btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
          color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
        }

        .btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
          transform: rotate(90deg);
        }

        .btn-toggle-nav a {
          display: inline-flex;
          padding: .1875rem .5rem;
          margin-top: .125rem;
          margin-left: 1.25rem;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        .btn-toggle-nav a:hover,
        .btn-toggle-nav a:focus {
          background-color: #cac9c9;
        }

        .btn-toggle-nav a {
          width: 200px;
        }

        html, body {
          overflow:hidden;
        }

        .fw-semibold {
          font-weight: 600;
        }

        .lh-tight {
          line-height: 1.25;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--  sidebar start  -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <i class="bi bi-layers" style="font-size: 1.5em; padding-right:10px"></i>
    <span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Layers</span>
    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
      <li class="border-top my-0"></li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dashboard-collapse" aria-expanded="false"> Natural Environment </button>
        <div class="collapse show" id="dashboard-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li>
              <svg width="25" height="15">
                <rect width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(245, 244, 244);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(25, 67, 207)" />
              </svg>
              <input class="list_item" data-id="78" type="checkbox">
              <label> SSSI </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg width="25" height="15">
                <rect width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(245, 244, 244);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(2, 68, 32)" />
              </svg>
              <input class="list_item" data-id="78" type="checkbox">
              <label> Local Nature Reserve </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg width="25" height="15">
                <rect width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(245, 244, 244);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(7, 155, 86)" />
              </svg>
              <input class="list_item" data-id="78" type="checkbox">
              <label> Green Corridors </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg width="25" height="15">
                <rect width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(245, 244, 244);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(14, 146, 54)" />
              </svg>
              <input class="list_item" data-id="78" type="checkbox">
              <label> Woodland </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg width="25" height="15">
                <rect width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(245, 244, 244);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(75, 143, 12)" />
              </svg>
              <input class="list_item" data-id="78" type="checkbox">
              <label> Woodland CAST</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg width="25" height="15">
                <rect width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(245, 244, 244);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(10, 131, 64)" />
              </svg>
              <input class="list_item" data-id="78" type="checkbox">
              <label> Wildlife Sites </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg width="25" height="15">
                <rect width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(245, 244, 244);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(6, 43, 7)" />
              </svg>
              <input class="list_item" data-id="78" type="checkbox">
              <label> Woodland Creation Sites long for test </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="border-top my-0"></li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#orders-collapse" aria-expanded="false"> Orders </button>
        <div class="collapse show" id="orders-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">New</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Processed</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Shipped</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Returned</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="border-top my-0"></li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#account-collapse" aria-expanded="false"> Account </button>
        <div class="collapse show" id="account-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">New...</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Sign out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="border-top my-0"></li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#histenv-collapse" aria-expanded="false"> Historic Environment </button>
        <div class="collapse show" id="histenv-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li>
              <svg width="20" height="13">
                <rect width="20" height="13" style="fill:rgb(151, 16, 16);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(255,153,0)" />
              </svg>
              <input class="list_item" data-id="78" type="checkbox"> Commercial and i like to be crazy indeed woith it test </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Weekly</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Monthly</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Annually</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="border-top my-0"></li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#openspace-collapse" aria-expanded="false"> Open Space </button>
        <div class="collapse show" id="openspace-collapse">
          <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
            <li>
              <svg width="20" height="13">
                <rect width="20" height="13" style="fill:rgb(151, 16, 16);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(255,153,0)" />
              </svg>
              <input class="list_item" data-id="78" type="checkbox"> Commercial and i like to be crazy indeed woith it test </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Weekly</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Monthly</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Annually</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

tried many different alignment properties with little success.